# PHP file path updating after unlink the previous file

Tags: php, file-upload

In my php file using file uploading control. After unlink previous file and update with new file it's not getting update with new image file. It's showing previous image in listing, when i refresh it's showing new image.  Using both listing and update screen in single php file. I used the document cache clear. Even it's not working.

```
 <?php 
     require_once("../config/config.php");
     header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
     header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    <?php
     require_once("../images.inc.php"); 
     if(Tools::isLoggedIn('admin') == false)
     { 
        Tools::redirectTo($link->rewrite_link(array("template"=>ADMIN_URI."index")));   
     } 
     $id_product =  (Tools::getVar("id_product")) ? Tools::getVar("id_rpoduct") : 0; 
     $page = intval(Tools::getVar("page"));
     $product = new Product($id_product);
     if(Tools::isSubmit("OnSave"))
     {
        $id_product =  Tools::getVar("id_product");
        $product = new Product($id_product);
        $product->name = Tools::getVar("name");
        $product->id_category = Tools::getVar("id_category");
        $product->short_description = Tools::getVar("short_description");
        $product->code = Tools::getVar("code");
        $product->weight = Tools::getVar("weight");
        $product->price = Tools::getVar("price");
        $product->size = Tools::getVar("size");
        $product->meta_title = Tools::getVar("meta_title"); 
        $product->meta_description = Tools::getVar("meta_description"); 
        $product->meta_keyword = Tools::getVar("meta_keyword"); 
        $product->status = Tools::getVar("status");     
        if(($product->name)=="")
        {
            $errors['err_name'] = "Name is required";
        }
        if(($product->short_description)=="")
        {
            $errors['err_short_description'] = "Description is required";
        }//edit on
        if($product->id_category <= 0)
        {
            $errors['err_id_category'] ="Parent Category is required";

        }
        if($product->code == '')
        {
            $errors['err_code'] ="Product Code is required";

        }
    if(sizeof($errors) == 0) 
         {
                if($id_product) {
                $product->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                if(isset($_FILES) AND sizeof($_FILES) AND $_FILES['image']['name'] != NULL && $id_product) {
                    $postimage = $product->postImage($id_product);              
                }           
                if($product->update())
                {
                    $redirect =  array("template"=>ADMIN_URI."product");
                    $session->set("success","Product Updated Successfully");
                    Tools::redirectTo($link->rewrite_link($redirect));  
                }
                else {
                    $errors['fail'] ="Please Try again Later";
                }
            }
            else {
                $product->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $product->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $id_product = $product->add(DB::RETURN_INSERT_ID);          
                if(isset($_FILES) AND sizeof($_FILES) AND $_FILES['image']['name'] != NULL && $id_product) {
                    $product->postImage($id_product);
                }
                if($id_product){
                    $redirect = array("template"=>ADMIN_URI."product");
                    $session->set("success","Product Added Successfully");
                    Tools::redirectTo($link->rewrite_link($redirect));
                }
                else {
                    $errors['fail'] ="Please Try again Later";
                }
            }
         }
    }
    if(Tools::getVar('action') == 'delete' && Tools::getVar('id_product') ) 
    {
        $id_product = Tools::getVar('id_product'); 
        $product = new Product($id_product);
        if($product->delete()) {
            $session->set("success","Product Deleted successfully");
            Tools::redirectTo($link->rewrite_link(array("template"=>ADMIN_URI."product"))); 
        }
        else {
            $errors['fail'] ="Please Try again Later";
        }

     }
     if(Tools::getVar('action') == "status_change"  && Tools::getVar('id_product'))
     {
        $id_product = Tools::getVar('id_product'); 
        $product = new Product($id_product);
        $product->status =Tools::getVar("status");
        $product->update();
        $session->set("success","Status updated successfully");
        Tools::redirectTo($link->rewrite_link(array("template"=>ADMIN_URI."product"))); 
     }
     require_once("header.php");
    ?>
```

My Image upload class like,

```
 <?php
    class Product extends ObjectModel
    {
    protected function uploadImage($id, $name, $dir, $ext = false)
        {
            if (isset($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']) AND !empty($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']))
            {           
                // Delete old image
                if (file_exists($dir.$id.'.'.$this->imageType)) {
                    $imagesTypes = $this->productImageTypes;
                    foreach ($imagesTypes AS $k => $imageType)
                    {
                        if (file_exists($dir.$id.'-'.stripslashes($imageType['name']).'.jpg')) 
                        {
                            unlink($dir.$id.'-'.stripslashes($imageType['name']).'.jpg');                       
                        }
                    }
                    unlink($dir.$id.'.'.$this->imageType);
                }
                // Check image validity
                if ($error = checkImage($_FILES[$name], $this->maxImageSize))
                    $_errors[] = $error;
                elseif (!$tmpName = tempnam(TEMP_DIR, 'SST') OR !move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'], $tmpName))
                    return false;
                else
                {
                    $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'] = $tmpName;              

                    // Copy new image
                    if (!imageResize($tmpName, $dir.$id.'.'.$this->imageType, NULL, NULL, ($ext ? $ext : $this->imageType)))
                        $_errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while uploading image.');
                    else {
                        $imagesTypes = $this->productImageTypes;
                        foreach ($imagesTypes AS $k => $imageType)
                            imageResize($dir.$id.'.jpg', $dir.$id.'-'.stripslashes($imageType['name']).'.jpg', (int)($imageType['width']), (int)($imageType['height']));
                    }
                    if (sizeof($_errors))
                        return false;
                    else
                    {
                        unlink($tmpName);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it your Imagination? or you have really tried it? because I can't see no code in your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your browser is displaying a cached version of the image since your saving new data to the same file name, try appending a query string containing a randomized string or timestamp to the image url when generating the HTML to display it. Something like this:

PHP

```
$image_tag='<img src="image-file.jpg?t='.timestamp().'" />';
```

This should make the browser fetch a fresh version of the image instead of using it's cached version.